# Magento 2 - Add 'per page' text inside option tag

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, toolbar

I want to **change the toolbar limiter** and to insert "**per page**" text inside `<option>` tag.

[image]

```
<div class="limiter">
    <label class="label" for="limiter">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Show') ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <select id="limiter" data-role="limiter" class="limiter-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?>
                <option value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_key ?>"<?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?>
                    selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_limit ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <span class="limiter-text"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('per page') ?></span>
</div>
```

I add this pages on my custom theme but even if I change something the changes are not displayed.

```
app/design/frontend/MyTheme/default/Magento_Theme/templates/html/pager.phtml
app/design/frontend/MyTheme/default/Magento_Catalog/template/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml
```

I need to add changes in other file?

Comment: which file you are editing ? what's your custom file path ?

Comment: is already in the post the files that I try to edit, pager.phtml and limiter.phtml

Comment: there are little corrections in code, try with updated code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are little corrections in your  `limiter.phtml` code and it will be displayed , here is updated file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
?>
<div class="field limiter">
    <label class="label" for="limiter">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Show') ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <select id="limiter" data-role="limiter" class="limiter-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?>
                <option value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_key ?>"<?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?>
                    selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_limit ?>
                    <span class="limiter-text"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('per page') ?></span>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**Keep your cache disabled or clean your cache .**

**Note:** Tested on LUMA Theme

Let me know if any problem

Comment: no is not work, so is not display any changes in this files: pager.phtml or limiter.phtml

Comment: only need to edit  limiter.phtml , try clearing your cache and deploying static files once

Comment: great @Robert ! cheers :)

Comment: can you tell me with something please? is there any way to change the click on limiter with hover state?

Comment: you want to make it show all options on hover state rather than clicking

Comment: yes this is the idea

Comment: I ll check that and will revert , meanwhile you can post question for this if not me than someone else definitely will help you. I will get back with solution for this.... I hope my current answer help you or you done it yourself then post the solution so that can help others as well

Comment: I will  try to get back with solution @Robert Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change to number of products then you do not need to edit any phtml file. There is an option in the backend at following path:

> Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront > Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values

Change the value of **Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values** according to your requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question but I assume you don't want the 'Per page' text to be rendered inside the dropdown options also. This can be achieved with the following code inside limiter.phtml file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
?>
<div class="field limiter">
    <label class="label" for="limiter">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Show') ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <select id="limiter" data-role="limiter" class="limiter-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?>
                <option value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_key ?>"<?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?>
                    selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                    <?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?><span class="limiter-text"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Per Page: ') ?></span><?php endif ?>
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_limit ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The path for this file is: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml

But you will want to over-ride this file inside your frontend theme to make the changes. Copy the file and place it here:

app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml